# how to push object into an nested array within a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, foreach

I am using an angularjs foreach and want to find data objects to load into another objects array.
When doing this, it seems like I am adding the variable and all the added objects change to the last variable values.

```
   var p = {};
   angular.forEach(d, function(personnel, index){
       if(wo.doc.job === personnel.job){
          p["EmployeeID"] = personnel.EmployeeID;
          p["Number"] = personnel.Number;
          wo.doc.personnel.push(p);
          console.log(personnel);
       }
    });
```

If this finds to 2 employees for a job, they are added and as i watch the wo.doc object after the second object is added the 2 added objects are the same as the last object.

Comment: Yes thank you, And thank you  member snow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new object in the loop.

```
   angular.forEach(d, function(personnel, index){
       if(wo.doc.WorkOrderDetailID === personnel.PrimeWorkOrderNum){
          var p = {EmployeeID: personnel.EmployeeID, Number: personnel.Number};
          wo.doc.personnel.push(p);
       }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, Why does that work different?

Comment: In your original code you only create one object ever. Here you create one object every iteration. And you want one object every iteration.